# How to set automatically a state indicator on awaitable tasks

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task

I want to use **awaitable task** in my wpf functions and I have a property Called **IsBusy** which shows loading status to user. I want to write a code which automatically set property IsBusy to true or false by waiting on a task be done or await. my tasks may be nested.

Comment: What is bad with: IsBusy=true; await YourTask();IsBusy-false;

Comment: Sounds like a plan.  You can do it!

Comment: I am looking for a lazy solution. a united code which I don't bother myself to write every time that indicate "hey I am waiting for a task".